# Override non null values from one dataframe to another

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I would like to override non null values from a dataframe to another dataframe with combination of first row and column (both being unique).

Basically, i am trying to join df2 on df1 only for non null values in df2, keeping df1 rows/column intact.

eg:

df1 =
[image]

df2 =
[image]

output =
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```py
output = df1.merge(df2, on='ID')
cols = [c for c in df1.columns if c!='ID']
for col in cols:
   output[col] = output[f'{col}_x'].fillna(output[f'{col}_y'])
   output.drop(columns=[f'{col}_x', f'{col}_y'], inplace=True)
```

Explanation:

1. At first, we merge two dataframes using `ID` as a key. The merge joins two dataframes and if there are columns with the same name it adds suffixes `_x` and `_y`.
2. Then we iterate over all the columns in df1 and fill the NA values in the column `col_x` using on the values in `col_y` and put the value into a new column `col`.
3. We drop the auxiliary columns `col_x` and `col_y`

**Edit:**
Still, even with the updated requirements the approach is similar. However, in this case, you need to perform a left outer join and fillna values of the second dataframe. Here is the code:

```py
output = df1.merge(df2, on='ID', how='left')
cols = [c for c in df1.columns if c!='ID']
for col in cols:
   output[col] = output[f'{col}_y'].fillna(output[f'{col}_x'])
   output.drop(columns=[f'{col}_x', f'{col}_y'], inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for above. But i need to update anything NON NULL in df2 to df1 on ID. For eg: In df1 if you see when ID =1 Address = A (Non Null) and in output for ID =1 Address being updated to Ind.

Comment: The answer is updated according to your requirements